# Cooperative work node.js

Tags: node.js, version-control

I'm new in cooperative web developing and I've recently got a new colleague to work with in my node.js based web app. We work remotely and therefore we need some environment to manage our files. 
We work in different areas, but from time to time, we make tiny changes in each others codes.
My need is some file manager (maybe online, maybe a node.js module) to work safely, prevent overwrites and keep track of changes.

If it's free, it's the best. If it has a small price, it's good and affordable, but if it comes with a heavier price tag, i might reconsider that option unfortunately.

(i also gladly accept any idea about cooperative web developing)

Comment: Github is what a lot of people are using now for cooperative/shared development.  It's free for public repositories or subscription for private repositories.

Comment: You definitely should take a look at GitHub as @jfriend00 have commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jfriend00 pointed out, [GitHub](http://GitHub.Com) is free and quite useful for collaboration and, as the name implies, it is based on [git](https://git-scm.com) which is the defacto standard for source code management these days.